# Best way to connect electric motor and differential in a tight space

Tags: automotive-engineering

I want to know, what the best way to connect an electric motor to a differential in a tight space. I first thought of a drive shaft, but the angle is to steep. The diff would be of a BMW E46 320d and the shaft of the motor has an outer diameter of 19.75mm and min 24.5mm depth and DIN 5480 teething.

Here is the side view of the setup
[image]

[image]
And the top view of the setup

[Here's more info about the electric motor](http://www.hribitec.com/si/attachment.php?id_attachment=10)

Comment: Use a hydraulic pump and motor, no angle problems then...